# 0 Calling js function declared in html file from different html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pages home.html and request.html
`request.html` have three js function `loadRequest()` , `loadUser()` and `loadSentRequest()`
default function that is called when `request.html` is called is loadUser()
Problem is i want to call `loadRequest()` in `request.html` to show user quick notification from `home.html`.
currently i tried with a tags

```
" href="requests.html:loadRequest()"
```

but its not working.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Is there any other way to call sub pages from html page.

Comment: uhm ... why you don't move those functions globally since you want to used them everywhere ?

Comment: where have you used the 'a' tag?

Comment: @Hawk <a " href="requests.html:loadRequest()" >Add & Remove</a>

Comment: your question is not clear to me. 
Can you show us URLs about each page? are the pages included in each other? I mean when you say the function is in request.html and you want to call it from home.html, does that mean the function is on the server? Where is the function actually?

Comment: @MihaiIorga by making it globally how can i call it along with calling request.html

Comment: By copy/paste or calling your JS file from both files.

Comment: @Joraid <a href="requests.html">Add & Remove</a>
request.html has three js functions.
is there a way to call any of them directly from other page like 
<a " href="requests.html:loadRequest()" >Add & Remove</a>

Comment: @Joraid but that functions is of no use in html
i want to call a js function on html file from my home page layout.

Comment: Javascript is a client side programming, means the browser *e.g. firefox* is the one that going execute the code. If you want to have the function available to be called, then, it must be loaded along with the page. If the function is not loaded with the page, then it doesn't exist. You can load the function by either copy/paste it into another file (I mean copy the <script> tag with it's code as well) OR you can place it into a separate file and request that file in both pages.

Answer (score 0):

Take out your function `loadRequest()` from `home.html`, put it in a separate javascript file, lets say `functions.js`, include that script in both `request.html` and `home.html` with something along the lines of

```
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

then simply call it like:

```
<a " href="javascript:loadRequest()" >Add & Remove</a>
```

from both `home.html` and `request.html`

Comment: but directly from home.html

Comment: you have one page loaded at a time - either `request.html`, or `home.html`. When the user goes to `request.html`, the `home.html` is gone, it doesn't exist anymore in browser's window

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to instruct a browser to leave the current page, go to a new URL and then execute some JavaScript in that page.

The closest you could come would be to load the second page in a frame, wait for the load event, then navigate through the DOM (`top.frames.etc...`) to fire the function in the frame.

If the frame is on a different origin, you'd need to look at using `postMessage` to ask the page to execute the function itself.

I'd generally prefer to do this by using a different URL for the second page (even if it is only adding a fragment identifier) and having code in the second page examine its own URL and fire the JS function if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

try this

put your js code in a different file.

externalfile.js //code

```
function loadRequest()
{
// code
}
```

then in your request.html in the head tag

```
<head>
<script src="externalfile.js"></script>
</head>

<a href="requests.html" onclick="loadRequest();">Add & Remove</a> // onclick can be changed to a dom event
```

that is inline handling of the event

more info on the link below
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: And this code should be placed in which page? The function doesn't exist at all. the function is available in *request.html*, yet, he wants to call it from *home.html*

Comment: he could use <script src="something.js"></script>

Comment: Well, yeah. Hope he gets the idea. Means he must load/call/fetch his JS code in both files to make it available.

Comment: it's not hard to link the file once you've made it. just adding the src tags in one line. and the function can be called, it's all done in the bacground by javascript engine

Comment: it seems someone -1 ur answer before you edit. Now your answer is reasonable. Lemme fix that :D +1